# Remove Line from String within txt file

Tags: php

Currently I have a code, which displays data from a txt file, and randomizes it after converting it into an array.

```
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));
$rand_keys = array_rand($array, 2);
```

I am trying to make it so that, after this random value is displayed.

```
$search = $array[$rand_keys[0]];
```

We're able to store this into another `txt` file such as `completed.txt` and remove the randomized segment from our previous `txt` file. Here's the approach I tried, and surely didn't work out with.

```
$a = 'test.txt'; 
$b = file_get_contents('test.txt'); 
$c = str_replace($search, '', $b); 
file_put_contents($a, $c);
```

Then to restore into a secondary file, I was messing with something like this.

```
$result = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(stripos($line, $search) === false) {
        $result .= $search;
    }
}
file_put_contents('completed.txt', $result);
```

This actually appears to work to some extent, however when I look at the file `completed.txt` all of the contents are EXACTLY the same, and there's a bunch of blank spaces being left behind within `test.txt`

Comment: Can you give an example of what the input and out files would look like?

Comment: @NigelRen The big issue I am having is that, when I `str_replace` the contents from the `txt` file, it leaves behind a white space, instead of removing that line entirely. Have been trouble shooting it for over an hour :(

Comment: Why yuo don't  remove from the array by the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some better ways of doing it (IMHO), but at the moment you are just removing the actual line without the new line character.  You may also find it will replace other lines as it just replaces the text without any idea of content.

But you will probably fix your code with the addition of replacing the new line...

```
$c = str_replace($search."\n", '', $b);
```

An alternative way of doing it is...

```
$fileName = 'test.txt';
$fileComplete = "completed.csv";

// Read file into an array
$lines = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
// Pick a line
$randomLineKey = array_rand($lines);
// Get the text of that line
$randomLine = $lines[$randomLineKey];
// Remove the line
unset($lines[$randomLineKey]);
// write out new file
file_put_contents($fileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));

// Add chosen line to completed file
file_put_contents($fileComplete, $randomLine.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I am upset, that it was this simple of a fix.

Comment: file_put_contents accepts mixed second argument so implode is not needed (untested though, but from my memory it works)

Comment: @Andreas, it does work, but would need a few changes (perhaps making the code simpler) as it does `implode('', $array)`, so I would be able to leave the new line processing out.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it resulted in implode "\n". In that case it's better to leave it as it is.